# Diazo in Plone 4.2 is enabled but the old theme is still activated

Tags: content-management-system, themes, plone, diazo

I have some problem with Plone 4.2 and the Diazo themes, i want to use Diazo themes.

I installed the skin and selected it enabled Diazo and Saved the Changes, but the Diazo theme is still not be acitvated on the hole website.

So how can i activate the Diazo theme??

greetings nameno

Answer (score 2):

1. install Diazo theme support (http://localhost:8080/Plone/prefs_install_products_form)
2. install your theme (http://localhost:8080/Plone/prefs_install_products_form)
3. in Diazo theme (http://localhost:8080/Plone/@@theming-controlpanel), check "enable theme" and select your theme
4. in the "advanced" tab, configure "Unthemed host names" to reflect your config (if you go on 127.0.0.1, by default, diazo will be disabled)
5. in the Theme configuration (http://localhost:8080/Plone/@@skins-controlpanel), check that your theme is enabled

With this, you have a working diazo theme.

Comment: thx a lot 

 this solved the problem :-) 

my mistake was on number 4